# How do I typeset a Fraktur x that looks like r?

Tags: fonts, symbols

How can I typeset this symbol?

[image]

And what is its name?

Comment: Where have you taken it from? It looks like the letter R with a specific font. The source of it would help you identify the font it uses.

Comment: looks like an x

Comment: @Johannes_B is correct.  Try: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
\mathfrak{r}\mathfrak{x}
\end{equation}
\end{document}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Weirdest x ever.

Comment: @Alenanno That is why reading old fraktur text is so difficult, until you get used to it.

Comment: @Alenanno Well, it is a different alphabet. What is weird about it?

Comment: Personally, i think blackletter fonts are much more pleasant to read.

Comment: @Johannes_B It doesn't look like an x, for example. :D

Comment: @Alenanno It doesn't look like an r either ;).

Comment: @cfr Well, the letter it resembles the most is an r with an odd serif. That's what it looked like, a serif. :P

Comment: @cfr: It's a letter often used in German Mathematics lesson at school, meaning `\vec{x}`.

Comment: @Alenanno I'm really not sure about that. Obviously we have different experiences with Fraktur and I'm by no means good with it, but I actually think it looks like a Computer Modern *x* with that two c's back to back shape, just with a more vertical middle and obviously the swash at the bottom left. (Just to offer what might be a helpful way to think about it and recognise it in future, not to attempt to be, y'know, smug or anything)

Comment: @Alenanno You must not be a topologist.

Comment: @KyleStrand Ha! I read that as *typologist* :)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have never ever seen that symbol in my life. We either use $\vec{x}$ or $\underline{x}$ or **x** although the last two are rather uncommon.

Comment: @idkfa: That doesn't mean it does not occur. I am teacher for Mathematics and Physics in BaWü, so believe me ;-)

Comment: See also [What kind of symbol is that?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201000/5001) for identifying Fraktur versions of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Special case of [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara/21#21) but deTeXify cannot

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Pretty standard for old fraktur fonts for the "x" to be an "r" with a hook.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
\mathfrak{r}\mathfrak{x}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Bringhurst tells us that blackletter fonts can be broken into 4 types, generally, based on how the lower case "o" is formed:

[image]

Here are some **FRAKTUR** examples exhibiting the x = r+ curl phenomenon:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Another type of blackletter font is **BASTARDA** (also known as Schwabacher).  Some of them also follow this convention:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's one that has a bastarda "o", but mixes and matches styles from across the blackletter spectrum.  Thus, I think it is a modern form

[image]

[image]

[image]

Next come the **ROTUNDA** fonts

[image]

These next two have the "r" + curl, but also adds an "x"-like stroke.  Perhaps this was a transition type of design to the modern "x".

[image]

[image]

[image]

This extra stroke on the "x" is also almost universal in the **TEXTURA** fonts:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Finally there is this one, that seems to elude categorization:

[image]

Whew... and that is only my blackletter fonts that exhibit this characteristic "x" as an "r" variant.  If you haven't guessed, I like fraktur and other blackletter fonts.  To show what a nut I am, I actually started characterizing letters by their construction.  Then, by looking at which constructions the fonts had, I could group them appropriately, or even tell imposters.

[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see, I ran out of steam before getting around to differentiating the "x".

Comment: Oh, do you have another screen shot example, i.e. one without 'Wehrmacht' -- that's a very negative term!!!

Comment: +1 Sorry for nitpicking, but ... Albrecht Dürer is missing the *ch* ligature.

Comment: @Johannes_B So true.  So long since I made those images, I forget if the font did not conveniently provide it, or if I just screwed it up.

Comment: I would like to upvote this answer a few times more :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B With that much excitement on your part, I decided to go pedal to the floor.  Please see my revision.

Comment: Man, don't get me wrong,  but you are crazy ;-)

Comment: Seems like JSL Blackletter is missing the long s. It's a pitty that so many fonts miss it :-(

Comment: @Johannes_B Crazy like a "for", with a curl on the "r".  I'll wear it as a badge of honor.

Comment: @Johannes_B Here is the motherlode, for many of my fonts:  http://moorstation.org/typoasis/designers/steffmann/index.htm

Comment: While many of your examples are correct, you also listed many where x is not r + curl, but r + curl + middle bar.

Comment: I had to sign up just to upvote this. Also wow, what's going on there with the 'y' that looks like an 'n', 'p' and 'd' at times.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen And as that extra middle bar arose in the figures, I gave it some extra discussion in the text.

Comment: @Johannes_B My old link seems to have gone bad.  But they seem to be here now: https://steffmann.1001fonts.com/

Answer (score 5):

Steven B. Segletes’ answer is excellent and got an upvote from me. It sticks to giving a narrow answer about the Fraktur *x* symbol in in math mode, and only shows how to display that.  It might also be useful to discuss how to use it in text mode.

### With fontspec

In a modern toolchain, you can use any TrueType or OpenType font.  One great, free, OpenType Fraktur font, not listed in the answer above, is [Unifraktur Maguntia](http://unifraktur.sourceforge.net/maguntia.html).  It isn’t packaged with CTAN, but you can download and install it.  This sample showcases the old-style Fraktur, the 21st-century variant and some of the alternative character variants.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}

% Unifraktur Maguntia with the default settings:
\newfontface\frak{Unifraktur Maguntia}[Ligatures={Common, Rare}]
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textfrak}{\frak}

% A deliberately antique version.
\newfontface\frakold{Unifraktur Maguntia}[
  CharacterVariant={11, 12, 13, 15, 19},
  Ligatures={Common, Rare, Historic}]
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textfrakold}{\frakold}

% Modernized Blackletter:
\newfontface\fraknew{Unifraktur Maguntia}[
  StylisticSet=1, % The "Easy Reading" variant.
  Ligatures={Common, Rare}]
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textfraknew}{\fraknew}

% Alternative Modernized Blackletter:
% This enables all the modernized character variants, and selects alternative
% forms for A and x.
\newfontface\frakvar{Unifraktur Maguntia}[
  CharacterVariant={1,2:1,3,4:1,5,6,7,8,9,10},
  Ligatures={Common, Rare}]
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textfrakvar}{\frakvar}

\newcommand\testcase{ASVYksxy}

\begin{document}

In traditional Fraktur, \emph{\testcase} would be written \textfrak{\testcase}.

A modern blackletter might display it as \textfraknew{\testcase}.

A variant is \textfrakvar{\testcase}.

Historically, \emph{schön Üben, etc.} might have been printed
\textfrakold{schön Üben, etc.}

\end{document}
```

[image: Maguntia Sample]

### In Legacy NFSS

The earliest blackletter fonts usable as a main font in LaTeX, and not just symbols in physics papers, were the Y fonts by Yannis Haralambous.  These were originally made in the early ’90s in Metafont, but are now available as Type 1 fonts (or as the Yannis fonts in the other answer).  There are several different packages with different encodings of them, but [`oldgerm`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mfnfss/oldgerm.pdf) was formerly a part of the LaTeX2e distribution and has both English documentation and a maintainer.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{oldgerm}

\begin{document}

\textgoth{Gotisch x}\\
\textswab{Schwabacher x}\\
\textfrak{Fraktur x}

\end{document}
```

[image: The Y Fonts]