# Alternative to $\mathfrak A$?

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

I love to use mathfrak letters.  However I need an `A' and the mathfrak A looks a lot like a U to me:

[image]

Are there alternative `mathfrak' looking fonts?

Comment: There are several alternatives, see e.g. on p. 119 of [the comprehensive catalogue](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf), otherwise see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/121799) how to look up a symbol.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [mathalfa](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathalfa) package? It provides an easy interface to (and various examples of) fraktur-type math alphabets.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58098/15925 for various possibilities.

Comment: You want to look at fraktur alphabets?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320403/how-to-typeset-a-gothic-r-symbol-with-a-curl/320407#320407. Of course, they are not set up currently for LaTeX math...

Comment: @marmot I don’t think this is a question about how to look up a symbol; the asker knows that the source is `\mathfrak{A}`. It’s a question about how to select a blackletter font that’s less Fraktur and more Antiqua, and use it in math-mode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### With unicode-math

You can select the Fraktur alphabet of any math font, or map any Unicode blackletter (or other!) font to the Fraktur alphabet.  You might try [UniFraktur Maguntia](http://unifraktur.sourceforge.net/maguntia.html) with its sets of character variants, including three forms of uppercase A.  Here is its “easy-reading” or “21st-century” variant.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
% From http://unifraktur.sourceforge.net/
% Stylistic Set 1 is the “Easy Reading” variant.  Character variant 4:1 is an
% alternative modern A.
\setmathfont[range=frak/{latin,Latin},
                   Scale=MatchUppercase,
                   StylisticSet=1,
                   script-features={},
                   sscript-features={}
            ]{Unifraktur Maguntia}

\begin{document}
\( \symfrak{ABCDEFGHIJKLM}\\
   \symfrak{NOPQRSTUVWXYZ}
\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Unifrak Maguntia Sample]

And a different variant A, plus other modernized letters:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
% From http://unifraktur.sourceforge.net/
% Stylistic Set 1 is the “Easy Reading” variant.  Character variant 4:1 is an
% alternative modern A.
\setmathfont[range=frak/{latin,Latin},
                   Scale=MatchUppercase,
                   CharacterVariant={4:1,5,6,7,8,9,10},
                   script-features={},
                   sscript-features={}
            ]{Unifraktur Maguntia}

\begin{document}
\( \symfrak{ABCDEFGHIJKLM}\\
   \symfrak{NOPQRSTUVWXYZ}
\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Unifrak Maguntia Variant]

This example keeps the default bold Fraktur, which Maguntia does not cover.  There are many other fonts in [Steven B. Segaletes’ list here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320403/how-do-i-typeset-a-fraktur-x-that-looks-like-r/320407#320407).

#### With NFSS

As Mico mentioned in the comments, you can select between the available Type 1 Fraktur fonts using [mathalpha](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf) (formerly `mathalfa`).

Another set of Fraktur fonts that aren’t designed for math mode, but can be used there, are the [Y fonts by Yannis Haralambous](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mfnfss/oldgerm.pdf), which are now available as Type 1.  For example, here is Gotisch.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018
\usepackage{oldgerm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Gotisch:    
\newcommand\varfrak[1]{\mathord{\text{\textgoth{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\( \varfrak{ABCDEFGHIJKLM}\\
   \varfrak{NOPQRSTUVWXYZ}
\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Gotisch]

ETA: Looking back at this answer in 2020, I notice a small bug in the MWE: I use `\text` to select a symbol alphabet in math mode.  In theory, formatting of the surrounding text, such as `\bfseries` or `\itshape`, would bleed through. This might be desirable if you’re including math symbols in a title where you want both `\bfseries` and `\boldmath`, and I don’t believe there’s any `\itshape`, `\scshape`, or so on for these fonts.

However, you might prefer to use `\DeclareMathAlphabet` instead (if you aren’t using legacy tools with a very limited number of math alphabets), or `\usefont` or `\normalfont` inside `\text`.

Comment: +1 Is symfrak a custom name or predefined?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner It’s defined in `unicode-math`. You could also use `\mathfrak` but give a package option to interpret it as `\symfrak`, so you don’t get ligatures like sz in math-mode. In practice, if you’re just writing `\mathfrak{A}`, they’re basically equivalent.

Comment: What on earth is the difference between "I" and "J" in the last font "Gotisch"?!?

Comment: @user21820 It’s a historic font that wasn’t intended for math papers, and historically those were the same letter. But thanks for reminding me about this. I notice a bug in my last MWE: I use `\text` to select the font in math mode, so theoretically, text-mode formatting such as `\bfseries` or `\itshape` would bleed through.

Comment: @Davislor: Oh! "I" and "J" were once the same letter? That is a really interesting thing that I did not know. Thanks for illuminating that. =)

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative you could try the fraktur style of `kpfonts` package: see the example below without to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX (fontspec/unicode characters).

[image]

In my humble opinion, they are not aggressive characters :-)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\newcommand{\Alphabet}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}

\begin{document}
 $\mathfrak{\Alphabet}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: So clean and tidy. Why on earth people like the horrifying mess of usual mathfrak is beyond me...

Comment: @user21820 De gustibus non est disputandum :-)

Comment: This changes every font in the document, not just mathfrak, which isn't ideal if you have a template you need to stick to. Is there a way to selectively change only the mathfrak font?

Comment: @Nathaniel Yes of course. There is a way selectively change only the mathfrak font of `mathfrak`. It is necessary declare every mathsymbol from the slot of the package, and to use them without to change the principal document. See the example https://tex.loria.fr/ctan-doc/macros/latex/doc/html/fntguide/node18.html `\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{0}{letters}{"0B}
   \DeclareMathSymbol{\lessdot}{\mathbin}{AMSb}{"0C}
   \DeclareMathSymbol{\alphld}{\mathalpha}{AMSb}{"0C}`

Comment: @Sebastiano thanks - but I'm afraid that looks like some kind of black magic to me. I have zero knowledge of how TeX handles fonts, and I can't begin to imagine how one would adapt this to replace `\mathfrak` characters with their equivalents from the `kpfonts` package, leaving everything else unchanged. I don't suppose you could shed a little more light on it, by any chance?