# XeTeX + STIX2 Errors: 'Too many symbol fonts declared.'; 'Symbol font Digits:m:n is not defined.'

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, mathspec, stix

I've recently been experimenting with typesetting and I stumbled upon an issue, where the following preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
Extension={.otf},
UprightFont={*-Regular},
BoldFont={*-Bold}, 
ItalicFont={*-Italic},
BoldItalicFont={*-BoldItalic}
]{StixTwoText}

\setmathfont(Latin,Greek){StixTwoText-Italic.otf}
\setmathfont(Digits){StixTwoText-Regular.otf} 
\setmathrm[BoldFont={StixTwoText-Bold.otf}]{StixTwoText-Regular.otf}
```

Generates errors written in the title. Removing both the `\setmathfont` and `\setmathrm` OR `\usepackage{stix2}` commands fixes the issue, but changes the math fonts.

Can I somehow use the STIX Two Text Italic font in math mode while still having the alternate math symbols defined in stix2?

Comment: Do you need `mathspec` at all? I believe that `unicode-math` is better with the fonts you want.

Comment: @egreg Perhaps that would be a good idea. I've never used `unicode-math`. How would I go about implementing the above code with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `unicode-math` for this, which supports STIX2 Math.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  BoldFont=*-Bold, 
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
]{STIXTwoText}

\setmathfont[
  Extension=.otf,
]{STIXTwoMath-Regular}

\begin{document}

$\alpha+x+\Gamma+\symrm{A}+\symbf{B}+123$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you remove the `math-style=ISO` option, you get

[image]

Note that `STIX` should be spelled all capitals; on case-insensitive file systems `Stix` might find the font, but the document wouldn't be portable.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. One more question: is it possible to change the other math fonts in this setup? For example, with `mathspec` I was able to change the `mathfrak` font style with `\setmathfrak`. Can I do something similar in `unicode-math`?

Comment: Ok, I seem to have found an answer to that question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437834/alternative-to-mathfrak-a

Thanks again for your help.