# Symbol: Curly T

Tags: symbols

How to produce this curly T?

[image]

I tried Detexify, but nothing.

Another letter 'A' of the same unknown family:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Haven't found that T yet.  Here are some others to consider:  `\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{yfonts}
\begin{document}
\swabfamily T
\gothfamily T
\frakfamily T
\initfamily T
\end{document} `

Comment: Also here: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/blackletterfonts.html and here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320403/how-do-i-typeset-a-fraktur-x-that-looks-like-r/320407#320407

Comment: https://fontzone.net/font-details/parchment, and http://4umi.com/web/font/serif/parchment.ttf

Comment: is that a scan of paper or do you have a  pdf?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Parchment is close but not exact

Comment: @KJO Yes, and as my Dad would have said, "close only counts in horse shoes and hand grenades"

Comment: Maybe a small version of the uppercase T in http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/frenchcursive/ ?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes My dad used to say a man on a galloping horse would not notice e.g.  possibly close enough to not matter  Romano seems closer with French Cursive (Bold?) I favour it could be more celtic

Comment: Closest I am getting is a Copperplate C  see https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/486318459747454151

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is from a book. I don't have the pdf.

Comment: Thanks to all, I'll wait if somebody can get the exact form.

Comment: From Scottish Handwriting study it is nearest to a style used mid 1800's The capital letter C is often looped at the top or bottom or both:  It would obviously help if we had more than one character to go by and the placement of that character in a word confirming it as T would be better since scripted Capital T is usually  more like a J

Comment: @KJO It's a capital T, no doubt. Anyway, I put another letter of the same category if you want to see the context.

Comment: @El_Bastaix what is the book's title? Maybe we could gather more information then.

Comment: Is this even a T? It could be a 'G' too.

Comment: The author is talking about "topologies". So I guess it's a T. The name of the book is irrelevant, because it's a very old Spanish book and there's no reference to the source of the "latex symbols" that it's using.

Comment: It just dawned on me this could also be an ampersand, which frequently are a stylized version of the latin "et".  Can you see a capital script E and small t in the image?

Comment: The title and the date of the book can help us identifying the font used (unless it's a handwritten glyph).

Comment: See an ampersand such as in the upper left of http://www.thinkstockphotos.com/image/stock-illustration-big-ampersand-symbol-collection/523879850.  While not this, can you see the similarity?  Or top row, 3rd from left of https://www.vectorstock.com/royalty-free-vector/hand-drawn-ampersands-union-words-for-invitation-vector-4410610

Comment: The "T" is similar (but not exactly the same) as in the "Mirella Script" font: https://www.dafont.com/mirella-script.font?text=A+Text&fpp=100&psize=l (but the "A" differ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may not be possible to get an exact match since we have no proof it could ever be an electronic font (simply scanned pixels) that could be either hand or lead inked

The closest modern electronic style based on two characters as A and T would be some form of Ronde (French School)

[image][image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Also I found https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/redrooster/tc-kingsley-rr/tckingsley-rr-swash-osf-light-italic/ , which is very close also.

Comment: You know this, but. In case anyone reading this has the follow-up question, “But how do I use that?”: `\usepackage{unicode-math}`, then after you load your math font, `\setmathfont[range=scr, Scale=MatchUppercase]{TCKingsleyRR-Light Italic}`. Also load a `bfscr` alphabet if you need bold math script. You can then use `\mathscr{T}` or `\symscr{T}`.

Answer (score 3):

The `T` symbol, for example as alternative, could also be drawn with [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/editor).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\curlyT{\scaleobj{0.11}{\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=5pt}}      
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.8pt,y=.8pt,yscale=-.8,xscale=1]
\draw [color={black}][line width=5] [line join = round][line cap = round]   (225,121.33) .. controls (217,123.33) and (202,112.33) .. (213,99.33) .. controls (224,86.33) and (243,112.33) .. (255,114.33) .. controls (267,116.33) and (281.3,112.09) .. (277,101.33) .. controls (272.7,90.58) and (257.36,100.06) .. (253,103.33) .. controls (248.64,106.61) and (226,156.33) .. (241,171.33) .. controls (256,186.33) and (279,166.33) .. (265,152.33) .. controls (251,138.33) and (237,166.33) .. (258,164.33) ;
\end{tikzpicture}}}

\begin{document}
\curlyT 

\end{document}
```

**ADDENDUM:**
Another possibility would be to use the [frcursive](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/frenchcursive/) package. The calligraphic font are similar to your picture.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{frcursive}
\begin{document}
{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont Here there is a curly A:} {\small \cursive{A}}. {\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont This is in classic default font Computer Modern. Here there is a curly T:} {\small \cursive{T}}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nicely Done, you'll have marmot looking over his shoulder soon :-)

Comment: @KJO Thank you for the compliment you have given me :-), but I'm not as good as the marmot. I am very happy that there are skilled and prepared people on our planet.

Answer (score 2):

Not a match, but a direction to look.  I'm now thinking this is not a script T, but an old-style ampersand, which used to take the form of the Latin "et".  I am thinking the one shown by the OP is in the same vein as the Baskerville 2 example below, but with the "t" more twisted around.

[image]

By the way, here is a great 3-part essay about the ampersand's history: https://shadycharacters.co.uk/2011/06/the-ampersand-part-1-of-2/.  Literally, it is believed the name comes from students reciting their alphabet, the last letter of which was "&", pronounced "and *per se*".

Comment: Sorry, but the wanted character is definitely a T.

Comment: @egreg I need new glasses!

Answer (score 1):

I've couldn't find the exact symbol either. Nevertheless, you could develop your own symbol with the help of Metafont. [Official Metafont Tutorial Page](http://metafont.tutorial.free.fr/)

An example is given in *The comprehensive LaTeX Symbol list - Page 220-223* [CTAN Website](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/)

Similar fonts: `\mathfrak{T}`in the `eufrak` package and `\mathcal{T}` in the `rsfso` package